# DataGridCheckBoxColumn updates source and is validated only after focus loss

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a problem with `DataGrid` from `WPFToolkit`. My grid has `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. When I change value of some cell in this column, validation and real source updating occures only after a cell has lost focus. So, if I change checkbox value in a cell and leave focus inside it, the property of a binded object wouldn't be changed.

Column's binding property `UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to `PropertyChanged` and `Mode` is set to `TwoWay`.

How can I make binding update my source object immediatly after a checkbox value has been changed?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know for the toolkit-version but with the .net4 version, the binding works as expected. Check your binding-declaration:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding YourProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

If it's a specific problem of the toolkit-version, create a  `DataGridTemplateColumn` and place a CheckBox in the cell-or edit-template and declare the binding on the `CheckBox`-control. This will help.

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn > 
       <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
             <DataTemplate> 
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YourProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 
             </DataTemplate> 
       </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I've just hit the same problem and I was missing the "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" (I didn't think it was needed as the cell already receives updates from the viewmodel via PropertyChanged notification). When I added the superfluous "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged", suddenly the changes I'm pushing to other rows in the datagrid appeared without me having to change rows.

Comment: See here http://www.telerik.com/forums/problem-with-gridviewcheckboxcolumn-in-wpf